# System Preferences->Sharing->Content Caching->Share: Internet Connection is not working with iOS Devices

Tags: networking, macos, ios

I have enabled Content Caching in System Preferences->Sharing and checked Share: Internet Connection because I want to share my computers internet connection with my iOS devices which are connected to the machine via USB. The note below this feature is:

```
Share this computer’s Internet connection and cached content with iOS devices connected using USB.
```

However, once enabled, my iOS device does not have an internet connection.

Any idea why this is not working or what I can do so it will work?

I would love to know if this is even supposed to work the way it seems it should or if I have misinterpreted the documentation.

I am using macOS 10.15.7.